# How to drag items into Folder in recycleview?

Tags: android, animation, android-recyclerview, drag-and-drop

I'm using Recycle view to populate my all list items and some folders also .I want to move that items by drag and drop into folder.

**What I've done so far**

I've successfully implemented rearranging my items using **ItemTouchHelper** [From this](https://medium.com/@ipaulpro/drag-and-swipe-with-recyclerview-b9456d2b1aaf).

Now I don't want to just change my items position but if I drag item onto **myfolder** , I want to delete that item from list and store it into that folder .

```
ItemTouchHelper.Callback _ithCallback = new ItemTouchHelper.Callback() {

        public boolean onMove(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {

            Collections.swap(list,viewHolder.getAdapterPosition(), target.getAdapterPosition());


            System.out.println("my first position  "+viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
            System.out.println("my finish position  "+target.getAdapterPosition());

            adapter.notifyItemMoved(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition(), target.getAdapterPosition());
            return true;
        }
```

I've searched through Android Arsenal also but couldn't find any lib .

I don't know how to use **ItemTouchHelper** to place my item over another item (folder in my case) .

Is there any way around to get X,Y coordinate of background item when I drop item over it ?

Is it possible with **ItemTouchHelper** or **dragListner**  ?

Is there any better approach to move item onto another in recycleview?